# Contact Form 7 checkboxes in popup

Tags: popup, contact-form-7

I have a form made with contact form 7. I'd like to be able to place a button within the form that when clicked opens a popup with 4 images, each with a checkbox. After making a choice and closing the popup I'd like the chosen check box to be added to the form data. How would I go about achieving this?

I've tried several things (plugins,  guesswork) and nothing is working so far.